# Certain updatings of list inside a function are propagated, while others are not, Why?

Tags: python, function

Consider two simple functions below for taking the last item out of a list:

```
def pop(arr):
    return arr.pop()

def my_pop(arr):
    last = arr[-1]
    arr = arr[:-1] # update the array
    return last
```

Let `a = list(range(10))`.

Using the first method and printing out `[pop(a) for i in range(3)]`, I got [9,8,7] and `a` is changed as expected. But if I use second method, I got [9,9,9] and `a` is not changed at all. What cause these differences?

I guess somehow this is due to the fact that assignment in Python is via pointer. Is that correct? Also, is there a rule of thumb on how updates of an argument are propagated to outside a function?

Comment: `arr.pop()` is a method of the list object and modifies the object. `arr = ...` assigns a new value to a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The command `arr = arr[:-1]` (asssignment to local parameter) needs to be changed to `arr[:] = arr[:-1]` (assignment to array indexes) in order to change the array.